# How can I change the color of a custom TreeView plus minus icon? WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I am wondering how to change the color of a custom plus and minus icon.
I was developing my software as in an attempt to make it look better, I wanted to change the TreeView icons. This is the code I'm using:

```
   [DllImport("uxtheme.dll", ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    private static extern int SetWindowTheme(IntPtr hwnd, string pszSubAppName, string pszSubIdList);
    public static void SetTreeViewTheme(IntPtr treeHandle)
    {
        SetWindowTheme(treeHandle, "explorer", null);
    }
```

To select the TreeView control the code is `SetTreeViewTheme(treeView1.Handle);` The outcome of that code is shown here:

[image: Image 1]

That is exactly what I wanted, however, the way the code works is that it gets a darker version of the TreeView background color selected, this is the issue. The color of my TreeView is already quite dark so by the code is making the icon darker based on my TreeView background color makes it very dark, well it turns out like:

[image: Image 2]

It's quite hard to see/read so I was wondering if there was a way I could control the color of the icons so I could change it so its easier to see/read.

Comment: You should add either WPF or Forms tag to your question.

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page!